# How to extract a part of matrix satisfying certain condition(s)

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a following matrix

```
matrix = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14}, {3, 100, 9,
     12, 15, 18, 21}, {4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28}, {5, 10, 15, 20, 100,
     30, 35}, {8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 100}, {9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 
    63}};
```

I want to extract part of Matrix excluding rows that have 100 (I used 100 to represent missing observation in my data-set) as an element.
I can get my results using the following codes:

```
result=Select[mat, #[[2]] != 100 && #[[5]] != 100 && #[[7]] != 100 &]
```

However, in my real data, I have a matrix with over 200 columns and I don't know the columns that have 100 as an element.

How can I obtain my results? If possible please let me know how  I can get part of matrix excluding all columns that have 100 as an element. In this case my final matrix should be

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example, this removes both rows and columns containing `100`

```
m = matrix[[Sequence @@ (Complement[Range@Length@matrix, #] & /@  Transpose@Position[matrix, 100])]];
m // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For removing rows containing 100 you could do (among others):

```
matrix /. {___, 100, ___} :> Sequence[]
```

or

```
DeleteCases[matrix, {___, 100, ___}]
```

Comment: @rka Just transpose the matrix first .... `Transpose@DeleteCases[Transpose@matrix, {___, 100, ___}]`

Comment: @ belisarius, thank you for your answer.  We can get the results for second part by transposing.  Still, can you please suggest answer to second part of the question as well without transposing? I want to lean if possible.

Answer (score 4):

My favorite method being the one in @belisarius' answer using `Part`, or a slight variation of it, (`matrix[[##&@@Complement@@@Transpose[{Range@Dimensions@matrix, Transpose@Position[matrix, 100]}]]]`), here are a few more, clunkier, alternatives:

```
matrix//MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
pattern = Join @@ ({{#, _}, {_, #2}} & @@@ Position[matrix, 100]);
m2 = ReplacePart[matrix, Thread[pattern -> Sequence[]]] /. {} -> Sequence[]
m2 // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
pattern2 = Join @@ ({{#, All}, {All, #2}} & @@@ Position[matrix, 100]);
m3 = matrix;
(m3[[##]] = Sequence[]) & @@@ pattern2; 
m3 = m3 /. {} -> Sequence[]; 
m3 // MatrixForm
(* same result *)
```

Comment: @ Kguler, Thanks for your answer. This gives some additional manipulation technique.

Comment: Your update is quite similar to my answer :)

Comment: @belisarius, indeed;) sorry, should have read more carefully.

Comment: @kguler Nah, I find myself re-discovering answers all the time. :D

Answer (score 2):

```
Cases[Transpose @ matrix, a_List /; FreeQ[a, 100]] // Transpose // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: @ eldo, thanks for your answer to second part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Postion` to exact the positions of `100`

```
tagPos=Position[matrix, 100] (*{{3, 2}, {5, 5}, {6, 7}}*)
```

Then using the `Last` to achieve the column of `100`

```
Rest/@Position[matrix, 100] (*{{2}, {5}, {7}}*)
```

So lastly, `Delete`

```
res=
 Delete[Transpose@matrix, Rest /@ tagPos] // Transpose;
MatrixForm@res
```

> $$
> \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  1 & 3 & 4 & 6 \\
>  2 & 6 & 8 & 12 \\
>  3 & 9 & 12 & 18 \\
>  4 & 12 & 16 & 24 \\
>  5 & 15 & 20 & 30 \\
>  8 & 24 & 32 & 48 \\
>  9 & 27 & 36 & 54
> \end{array}
> \right)
> $$

#### Or

If you hope to delete the row or column that owns `100`, you can do like this:

```
res1 = Delete[Transpose@matrix, Rest /@ tagPos] // Transpose;
(*remove the column that containing 100*)
res2 = Delete[res1, Most /@ tagPos];
(*remove the row that containing 100*)
MatrixForm@res2
```

> $$
>   \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  1 & 3 & 4 & 6 \\
>  2 & 6 & 8 & 12 \\
>  4 & 12 & 16 & 24 \\
>  9 & 27 & 36 & 54
> \end{array}
> \right)
> $$

Comment: @ ShutaoTang Thank for your reply. This gives me an additional method of doing my job.

Comment: @rka,my pleasure!:-)